# Bind Listview Inside Listview for sub menus(child menus)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am little confused for creating website menu & sub menus which is completely dynamic & made from database. For Menus I used Listview Control which is fine now all menus have submenus(child menu) as well which is based on menus. Now I don't understand how to do it. I guess using nested ListView would be good for this but I need an hint how to bind nested listview?

This is my main Listview

```
<asp:ListView ID="mainMenu" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <li><asp:HyperLink ID="mainLinks" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("name", "~/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
              <ul class="super-child">
                       <asp:ListView ID="childMenu" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <li><asp:HyperLink ID="cat3" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("category") & Eval("name", "/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:ListView>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView> 


Private Sub bigMenu()
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mainMenu WHERE status = 'active' order by CAST(position as SIGNED INTEGER) asc"
                cmd.Connection = con
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    mainMenu.DataSource = dt
                    mainMenu.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ListView ItemDataBound to bind your nested listview. ItemDatBound will get rows value for you. See the below code I done for you

```
<asp:ListView ID="mainMenu" runat="server" DataKeyNames="enter column name you want">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <li><asp:HyperLink ID="mainLinks" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("name", "~/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
              <ul class="super-child">
                       <asp:ListView ID="childMenu" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <li><asp:HyperLink ID="cat3" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("category") & Eval("name", "/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:ListView>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView> 

Protected Sub onItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim itm As ListViewDataItem = CType(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
            Dim name As String = mainMenu.DataKeys(itm.DataItemIndex)("enter your datakeyname")
            Dim childMenu As ListView = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("childMenu"), ListView)
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
            Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column = '" + name + "'"
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        childMenu.DataSource = dt
                        childMenu.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```